# symfony unlink warning in Apache error log

Tags: apache, symfony1, error-log

I have a symfony 1.4 project that is continually putting the following warning in the Apache error log:

```
[Wed Sep 26 06:18:22 2011] [error] [client 192.168.100.12] PHP Warning: unlink(/var/cache/project-ttp/device/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php): No such file or directory in /usr/share/project-ttp/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php on line 132
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: did you change cache folder for your symfony project?

Comment: I have the same issue now, and have not changed the location of my cache.

Comment: it looks like unhandled bug, i fixed it in my symfony 1.4 fork https://github.com/palmic/symfony1/commit/2a10db2dd7a7bafe36561b5bd10037f8b8851a6f